# How do I add a single actionListener for multiple buttons to add the sequence of buttons pressed to an arrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I am writing a program to play the Simon game. My goal is to store the sequence of the buttons pressed into an Array List and then compare it to another Array List that has a randomly generated sequence. My problem is, my code is only able to register a single button press. My code is posted below. I browsed through similar posts but I was not able to figure out a way to adapt the explanations to solve the problem on my own. My code is below. Thank you.

```
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Random;

  public class Simon implements ActionListener, MouseListener
  {
      private List<Integer> input;
      private List<Integer> pattern;

      private int round, score, flashed;

      private Random rand = new Random();
      JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;
      public Simon()
      {
          input = new ArrayList<>();
          pattern = new ArrayList<>();

          round = 1;
          score = 0;

          JFrame f=new JFrame("Simon");
          b1 = new JButton("");
          b2 = new JButton("");
          b3 = new JButton("");
          b4 = new JButton("");
          b1.setBounds(0,0,200,200);
          b1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
          b2.setBounds(0,200,200,200);
          b2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
          b3.setBounds(200,200,200,200);
          b3.setBackground(Color.RED);
          b4.setBounds(200,0,200,200);
          b4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

          b1.addActionListener(this);
          b2.addActionListener(this);
          b3.addActionListener(this);
          b4.addActionListener(this);

          b5 = new JButton("Start");
          b5.setBounds(100, 500, 70, 30);
          b5.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

          f.add(b1); f.add(b2); f.add(b3); f.add(b4); f.add(b5);
          f.setSize(600,600);
          f.setLayout(null);
          f.setVisible(true);

          f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      }


    public void play()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= score; i++)
        {
            flashed = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
            if (flashed == 1)
            {
                pattern.add(1);
                b1.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
                b1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }

            if (flashed == 2)
            {
                pattern.add(2);
                b2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
                b2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            }

            if (flashed == 3)
            {
                pattern.add(3);
                b3.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
                b3.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }

            if (flashed == 4)
            {
                pattern.add(4);
                b4.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
                b4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }

            System.out.println("pattern: " + pattern);
        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == b1)
            input.add(1);
        if (e.getSource() == b2)
            input.add(2);
        if (e.getSource() == b3)
            input.add (3);
        if (e.getSource() == b4)
            input.add(4);
        System.out.println("input: " + input);

        result();
    }

    public void result()
    {
        if ( pattern.equals(input))
        {
            score++;
            round++;
            pattern.clear();
            input.clear();
            play();
        }
        else
        {
            pattern.clear();
            input.clear();
            round = 1;
            System.out.println("Game over. Score: " + score);
            score = 0;
        }

    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Simon app = new Simon();
        for (int i = 0; i < app.round; i++)
        {
            app.play();
        }


    }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have made a mistake often made by new GUI coders of implementing a delay with a sleep. That's not the way to do it in Swing (or, I believe, any UI framework). You need to have a `Timer` that starts when the button is pressed and then returns control to the framework so it can continue to respond to the user. The timer can then perform whatever action is required after a delay. I suggest fixing that issue first to see if it resolves the problem. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: Don't clear the `input` `List` in `result`